# logrotation- rotate and maxage command

Tags: logrotate

please check the below script where I have to rotate the file for 30 days and its moved into the backup directory after rotation. So as I have used rotate 30 and maxage 30, when the logrotation happens for the 31st day will the oldest file which is 30 days older get deleted..?

```
/data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test/test.log {
        daily
        copytruncate
        create 775 root wsdepl
        dateext
     dateformat .%Y.%m.%d
        rotate 30
     maxage 30
        missingok
        #notifempty
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
           cd /data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test
           gzip test.log.*
           mv /data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test/*.gz /data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test/backup
        endscript
}
```

Please help me on this. Thank you..

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you appear to be using logrotate, but then you're manually zipping logs and moving them somewhere else yourself as well, from *within* logrotate.  Can you describe what you're trying to achieve long term.

Comment: when I tried using compress along with postrotate it wasn't working,later I came to know that postrotate always runs before compression for logrotate. So I manually zipped the files and moved into backup folder...If you can help me using compress function in my script it will be useful as well

Comment: That's not an answer to my query - can you explain, in your original question, exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the test.log file is rotated daily and it creates a file with date extension after rotation. Inside postrotate the rotated file is  zipped and moved into a new directory called backup.

Comment: Have you found the answer?